# Mysql gives on ClassCastException : java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long on Amazon EC2

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, amazon-ec2, classcastexception

I have a Java servlet project and I recently deployed on amazon ec2 instance. I installed java6, mysql & tomcat7 on ec2 and run my app. But all of a sudden, the website starts to give me this ClassCastException all over the place.
"org.mybeans.factory.RollbackException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long" 
But the weird thing is the same project worked perfectly fine on my local machine. I simply scp the .war file onto the ec2 and run it.
Have anyone met similar problems before? Could anyone offer some advice how to fix this? Thanks! (This is my first question here, sorry for the messy format..)

Comment: Please post the stacktrace, or an example of one if they differ. Also, what does this have to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html BigInteger is returned from the the MySQL value UNSIGNED BIGINT where just BIGINT returns a Long.
Is there a difference in the db schema between your local machine an ec2?

Comment: The only difference I can notice now is that my local machine is running mysql-5.5.24ubuntu12.04 and the ec2 is running mysql5.5.29ubuntu12.04. Other than that, I think all the development environment, java, tomcat should all be the same. I just don't understand why the project works on my machine but not ec2.

Comment: If you could post the relevant lines of code where the exception is thrown as well as the database schema it is using it might help diagnose the problem.
Right now there is not much to go on.